# Grid de 3 columnas

Tags: html, css

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente código:

HTML:

```css
.contenedorgrid {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0px;  margin: 0px;

    
}

.cajas {

  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
     padding-left: 30px;
    
    
}

.caja {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 270px;
   

}
```

```html
    <div class="contenedorgrid">
                            <div class="cajas">
                                <div class="caja">
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                k
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                k
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                l
                                </div>
                                 <div class="caja">
                                k
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                k
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                k
                                </div>
                                <div class="caja">
                                l
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Y necesito que la caja se divida en 2, es decir que la parte de arriba sea azul y la parte de abajo sea blanca y no sé como hacerlo, cuando creo otra caja dentro de la otra me la sobre expone raro.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Tengo mal mi código y por eso no puedo?

gracias!

Comment: ¿Te entiendo bien si quieres que todas las cajas rojas se dividan en dos partes donde la parte arriba es azul y la parte abajo es blanca?

Comment: Y el texto que pusiste en cada caja donde debe quedar arriba, abajo o al medio?

Comment: exacto la parte ade arriba azul y la de abajo blanca. La caja blanca es la que tiene texto.  Tiene que verse en solo la caja blanca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar % para anchura y altura:

```
.azul {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.blanca {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
.contenedorgrid {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.cajas {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.caja {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 270px;
  border: 2px solid black
}

.azul {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.blanca {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedorgrid">
  <div class="cajas">
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        k</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        k</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        l</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        k</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        k</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        k</div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
      <div class="azul"></div>
      <div class="blanca">
        l</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```